# SQL (not exists command)

Tags: sql, exists

```
create table class (cid integer primary key , cname text);

create table student (sid integer primary key, sname text);

create table attend ( cid integer , sid integer, grade integer);

Select A.cid, S.sname, S.sid
From Student S, Attend A
Where S.sid=A.sid and not exists
(Select *
From Attend A2
Where A2.cid=A.cid and A2.grade > A.grade);
```

I don't understand why the result is:

For each class id display the names of students that got the maximum grade in this class

I thought it would instead return the student with minimum grade for each class.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the **`not`** operator there - this query select the student(s) that **doesn't** have any other student with a greater grade than him - i.e., he has the maximum grade.